# Is it possible to generate Spring hateoas entities with openapi

Tags: java, spring, openapi, openapi-generator, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to use openapi to generate an enitity that uses the spring-hateoas RepresentationModel class.

Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.hateoas.RepresentationModel;


import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "User")
@ToString
public class User extends RepresentationModel<User> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date joinedDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Chat Chat;
}
```

I can't find any examples on how to generate an entity like this and for it to extend the  RepresentationModel class with type User.

Is this type of generation possible? If so how?

I'm using:

```
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>6.2.1</version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hateoas is a [configurable option/feature](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/#:%7E:text=org.openapitools-,hateoas,-Use%20Spring%20HATEOAS) in the spring generator.

Add this config option to your `openApiGenerate` task and it will automatically add the `RepresentationModel` to your generated models.

```xml
<configOptions>
  <hateoas>true</hateoas>
</configOptions>
```

Comment: Hi @tbatch, good morning,  I enabled the flag, the problem is that it adds it to all models, and when I enter swagger the examples from the request are for each object with links, do you know any way to remove just the request?